# is their possible to call tableviewcontroller using xib button in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have create a custom uiView and load in AlertViewController Button in Appdelegate ...Here My problem is Inside My Custom UIView I created a One Button..When I click that Button..I want to Move a tableviewcontroller in storyboard using their id...But I got UIKit Error..

```
- (IBAction)RegisterBttn:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tet"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: [CustomViewForAccept presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fba117ae060
2017-08-17 15:29:33.523 ScrollViewSample[5224:152680] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomViewForAccept presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fba117ae060'
I got this error Sir

Comment: Only view controllers can present other view controllers, views can't do that.  You should move your code into whatever view controller is active and either connect that to your button or have the button handler tell the controller to present the new controller.